# Group text as per the object in an image using Google Vision APIs

Tags: python-3.x, google-vision

let's say an image consist of multiple objects. Using Google vision APIs, I am able to detect these objects.Now I want to extract text based on each object.(i.e I want to group text with the corresponding object).How can this be achieved?

I tried to detect object, which returned the **normalized vertices** of each object.The same process is followed for text, which returns vertices in **pixels**.How can I map the text to the corresponding object in the image ?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)